# Excel txt file import (specific columns) into a table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I found this forum while I was trying to sort out my VBA code. I only have very little experience in VBA programming so far. That is why I have researched since two days for a solution for my problem, without success. However, I am very interested in impoving my programming skillsa and I hope you can help me to do so.

Basically I would like to import a TXT file into the active Excel workbook, sheet named "DataImport" at the end of the table named "TblDataImport".

The TXT file consists of 13 columns which are separated by tabs:

1. row: CompanyName
2. row: **Date** ***Name*** CustomerGroup CustomerNo **SalesOrder** ItemNumber ItemGroup LineStatus ***Quantity*** ***Price*** ***Discount*** DiscountPercentage **NetAmount**
3. row: All corresponding values...

I dont't need to import the first and the second row since the table where I would like to import the data to aready exists including headings. Also I only need 7 out of the 13 columns, those that are formated in bold. It would be perfect if the user could choose the text file using an open file dialogue.

If I open the TXT file manually and paste its content into Excel, it is already included
in the right columns. So there should not be any pitfalls with regard to formatting.

I am curious about the solutions you come up with.

With the macro recorder I can only fulfil some of my conditions:

```
Sub DataImport()  
' DataImport Makro  
    Sheets("DataImport").Select  
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _  
        "TEXT;C:\Users\Sales.txt", Destination:=Range _  
        ("$A$1"))  
        .Name = "AxaptaSales"  
        .FieldNames = True  
        .RowNumbers = False  
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False  
        .PreserveFormatting = True  
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False  
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells  
        .SavePassword = False  
        .SaveData = True  
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True  
        .RefreshPeriod = 0  
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False  
        .TextFilePlatform = 850  
        .TextFileStartRow = 1  
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited  
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote  
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False  
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True  
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False  
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False  
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False  
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(4, 1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1)  
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True  
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False  
    End With  
End Sub
```

However this code only pastes all columns into cell A1 (not at the end of the table). Also it includes the first and second row as well as the columns I don't need.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use another sheet to simply do data import and erase the unnecessary columns manually ?

Comment: Use macro-recorder, and try to import your TXT using Ribbon `Data > From Text` option. Then you should modify the recorded code to fulfill your wishes)

Comment: Wow you are very fast :)

Comment: @ Alexandre: The data from the text file is imported on a daily basis. So it would be cumbersome to first manually delete the columns I don't need and then manually copy it at the end of the table "DataImport". But maybe this could be automatedby the macro?

Comment: @ Peter: I already tried the macro recorder and it works fine, but the recorder does not allow me not to import the first two rows as well as to import the data at the end of the table. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Samuel in case temporary sheet is not an option for you, read CSV using `ADODB.Stream`, perform required manipulations and then put the result to the sheet. However, this will be much more complicated than intermediate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to the code above this will add it to the end of the data already in the worksheet

```
Sub DataImport()

   Dim LastRow As Integer
   Dim LastRow2 As integer
    LastRow = Range("A65536").end(xlup).row
    LastRow = LastRow + 1  
 ' DataImport Makro  
Sheets("DataImport").Select  
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _  
    "TEXT;C:\Users\Sales.txt", Destination:=Range _  
    ("$A" & LastRow))  
    .Name = "AxaptaSales"  
    .FieldNames = True  
    .RowNumbers = False  
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False  
    .PreserveFormatting = True  
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False  
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells  
    .SavePassword = False  
    .SaveData = True  
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True  
    .RefreshPeriod = 0  
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False  
    .TextFilePlatform = 850  
    .TextFileStartRow = 1  
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited  
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote  
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False  
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True  
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False  
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False  
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False  
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(4, 1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1)  
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True  
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False  
End With
Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + 1).entireRow.delete
LastRow2 = Range("A65536").end(xlup).row
Range("H" & LastRow & ":M" & LastRow2).entirecolumn.delete
```

End Sub

I think this should do as you require(But I am still a novice myself)